# How should I connect a new light fixture to my wiring?

Tags: electrical, ceiling, old-house

I’m new at electrics (UK-based) and am rewiring a new light. All the advice I’ve read notes that the black wires are L & N and the red are the loop with the bare coppers being the ground but when I opened mine up, the red were linked to the L & N. I’ve only got a three-way connection so can I just connect the blacks together with a wire connector cap?

[image]

Comment: Where are you located? Wiring "normal" colors varies by location (country) but electricity doesn't care what color wire it's in, sometimes you have to ignore colors and use a voltmeter to test which wire is used for what purpose - once you figure it out, you can label the wires with tape, markers, or paint for future use. Please [edit] your country into the Question.

Comment: Thanks Fredric. I’m UK based and have added that to the question. I’ve labelled which ones are live and neutral as they came out and yes, I assumed that the black/red could be used in either capacity but wanted to double check. I’ve tried rewiring to connect the same way and it doesn’t seem to have caused any damage!

Comment: That ceiling box has terminals so you should not need to add your own connectors.     Why not wire the new fixture the same way as the old one?  (Although, if the picture is of the old one, there is room for improvement, as the bulb socket currently has a live terminal with the switch off.)  Do you have a meter to determine which wire is the live one?  Should be one of the red ones.